# Transformation from $\delta(x)$ to $f(x)$ based on a parameter

Tags: functions

Here $\delta(x)$ is the dirac-delta function.

Are there known transformations $T$ that achieve this for a function $f(x)$ based on a parameter $a$ (say, $0 \le a \le 1$)?

$$T_{a}[f(x)]$$

$$T_{0}[f(x)] = \delta(x)$$
$$T_{1}[f(x)] = f(x)$$

and it should smoothly vary between $a=0$ and $a=1$ (not particular about how it should transition, but simpler the better. Edit: It should not involve a delta function when $a > 0$, assuming f(x) itself doesn't contain any).

Comment: Good one :) I should have mentioned, but I want to stay away from $\delta(x)$ when $a > 0$.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking for but what about $$f(x)(e^{-x^2})^{1/a-1}$$

Comment: @juanarroyo, when $a=0$, doesn't this result in $f(x) e^{x^{2}}$ and not $\delta(x)$?

Comment: Use it for $a>0$, and use $\delta (x)$ for $a=0$.

Comment: Sorry I see my notation may have been misleading. It's supposed to be $$f(x)(e^{-x^2})^{\frac{1}{a}-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try a linear combination of $f$ with an [approximation to the identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#nascent_delta_function).